# testing if the infinite series are converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

here are two problems on testing if the infinite series are conv. or div.

1. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{{{7\sqrt[6]{n^{13}}+2n}}}{{\sqrt[3]{27n^{9}-10n+16}}}$
2. $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(n!)}$

the first one I couldn't do :(

but the second one here is what I did using the ratio test I got that

$$\frac{\ln(n!)}{\ln((n+1)!)}=\frac{\ln(n)+\cdots+ \ln(2)}{\ln(n+1)+\cdots +\ln(2)}<1$$

which I thought would be effective but it isn't :(

Comment: The fact that the ratio is less than $1$ is not enough: You need to know whether the LIMIT OF the ratio is less than $1. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Oh no!! what should I do then :(

Answer (score 2):

Both are divergent. In the first one, the term is $\sim 7n^{13/6}/3n^3= \frac 73 n^{-5/6}$,
as one know $\sum n^{-p}$ is divergent when $p<1$. In the second one, the term is greater
than $\frac{1}{n\ln n}=\frac{1}{\ln n^n}$, you see $\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln x}dx$ is divergent so by the integral test $\sum  \frac{1}{n\ln n}$ is divergent, so $\sum \frac{1}{\ln n!}$ is more divergent.

Comment: thank  but note that I didn't learn the  integral test  yet and I'm not allowed to use it

Comment: #1 also needs the integral test (to show $\sum n^{-p}$ is divergent when $p<1$), in fact, I don't know how to show this without the integral test.

Comment: Sorry for the comment above, actually you can compare with $\sum \frac 1n$ and there is some tricks to show $\sum \frac1n$ divergent without integral test.

Answer (score 2):

In the first one, you have
\begin{align}
& \frac{n^{13/6} + \text{comparatively negligible things}}{n^3 + \text{comparatively negligible things}} \\[12pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {n^{5/6} + \text{comparatively negligible terms}} \ge \frac {\text{some constant}} {n^{5/6}} \\[6pt]
& \text{(and “constant” means not changing as $n$ changes)}
\end{align}
Here I would work on trying to prove that the $n$ term of the series is greater than or equal to some constant multiple of $n^{-5/6}.$

\begin{align}
& \frac{7\sqrt[6]{n^{13}}+2n}{\sqrt[3]{27n^9-10n+16}} = \frac{7 + \frac 2 {n^{7/6}}}{\sqrt[3]{27n^{5/2} + \frac {10} {n^{11/2}} + \frac{16}{n^{13/2}}}} \\[12pt]
\ge {} & \frac 7 {\sqrt[3]{27n^{5/2} + 10 n^{5/2} + 16n^{5/2}}} = \frac 7 {n^{5/6} \cdot\sqrt[3]{27+10+16}}
\end{align}

And $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^{5/6}} =  +\infty.$

Answer (score 1):

As @Yuval showed, the first one diverges. 
Since the integral test is not allowed, you can use direct comparison test: 
Comparing your series to the harmonic series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$, which diverges, gives us 
$\frac{7}{3}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{5}{6}}}>\frac{1}{k} \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{7}{3}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{5}{6}}}>\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$. 
Now, by the direct comparison test, the series diverges.

Remarks: 
(1) I used the asymptotic order of your series, but it works similar with the original term. 
(2) Divergence of the harmonic series can be proven by direct comparison test as well. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))